# Amazon advertisement using iframe not customizable

Tags: html, css, iframe, amazon-web-services

I am trying to make this amazon ad appear in the center of the page. This is what it looks like before I add anything to it:

```
        <iframe src="http://rcm-na.amazon-adsystem.com/e/cm?t=websitcom05-20&o=1&p=26&l=ur1&category=primeent&banner=1XSEYPQA2R6RS2D2B802&f=ifr" width="468" height="60" scrolling="no" border="0" marginwidth="0" style="border:none;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

And here it is after I have added the class "center" to it:

```
<iframe class="center" src="http://rcm-na.amazon-adsystem.com/e/cm?t=websitcom05-20&o=1&p=26&l=ur1&category=primeent&banner=1XSEYPQA2R6RS2D2B802&f=ifr" width="468" height="60" scrolling="no" border="0" marginwidth="0" style="border:none;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Here is my css code for the center class:

```
.center {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
 }
```

I do not have styling applied to the iframe element.

You can view it here:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the `iframe` element is `inline`. Inline elements don't respect margins, therefore you need to make the element `block` level in order for the margins to work.

```
iframe.center {
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
}
```

As an alternative, you could also just place `text-align:center` on the parent element. Since `inline` elements respect this property, it would effectively center the `iframe` by default.